# How to escape backslash in // comment

Tags: c++, escaping, comments, c-preprocessor, clang++

I have a comment that ends with backslash. Something like

```
...

// use \

..
```

Clang(++) warned me, that this is multi-line comment

```
warning: multi-line // comment [-Wcomment]
    // use \
           ^
```

So I try add some whitespace at the end, but didn't help. Can I escape backslash somehow?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that the comment *must* end with a backslash?

Comment: I ran into this when I tried to use the ``:\`` face in a comment :\

Comment: Old post, but for me just adding a (white)space after the backslash seemed to work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The foundation of the issue is the definition of a line continuation.

When a line ends with a `backslash-newline` combination or `<backslash><whitespace><newline>` combination, the compiler appends the next line of text to the present line of text.  This can be demonstrated with macros:

```
#define ME {\
cout << "me\n" \
}
```

The above will be treated as the single line:

```
#define ME {cout << "me\n"}
```

The compiler is complaining because your "//" comment extends to the next line because the '\' continuation character.

**Solution:**
Put other characters after the '\'.
Examples:

```
  '\'
  \ ending character
```

Answer (score 5):

While this is not a technical solution, I would take that as a hint to write a better comment:

```
// use \ (backslash) instead of the normal slash here, because ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grave Accent (`)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // print `\`
    cout << "DONE" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A regular quote or double quote should work.  Anything after the backslash, except whitespace and newline, should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have code like this:

```
#define foo {int x = 123; \
cout << x << endl; \
}
```

And you want to comment it out:

```
//#define foo {int x = 123; \
//cout << x << endl; \
//}
```

Above code should work fine. On the other hand, if you write:

```
#define foo {int x = 123; \
cout << x << endl; \
} \
```

Then foo may work (if next line is empty) but you get in trouble if you comment it out. Just remove the last back slash. Otherwise don't end the line with backslash unless it's meant to connect...