# C preprocessor: line continuation: why exactly comment is not allowed after backslash character ('\')?

Tags: c, comments, c-preprocessor, backslash

Valid code:

```
#define M xxx\
yyy
```

Not valid code:

```
#define M xxx\/*comment*/
yyy

#define M xxx\//comment
yyy
```

Questions:

1. Why comment is not allowed after backslash character (`\`)?
2. What the standard says?

UPD.
Extra question:

1. What is the motivation / reason / argumentation behind the requirement that (in order to achieve splicing of physical source lines) backslash character (`\`) must immediately follow by a new-line character? What is the obstacle to allow comments (or spaces) after the backslash character (`\`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape backslash in // comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286253/how-to-escape-backslash-in-comment)

Comment: The character after the backslash must be a newline, not a standard slash or space. I can't check the order of operations right now (line splicing before comment removal), but if line splice happens after comment removal, the comment removal works by replacing comment with a space anyway

Comment: @tibi: No, that is not relevant.

Comment: "motivation / reason / argumentation"? No real answer ... but this usage by the preprocessor kinda mimicks the usage of the compiler when backslash appears in strings or character literals: the backslash and the following character form a group the two characters (or more) go together... you cannot have `"foo\" "tbar" /* string with inner tab */`

Comment: motivation / reason / argumentation: line splicing happens (as if) before tokenization and token classification.  Thus, at the time that line splicing is being performed, at is not possible to detect whether the characters that follow constitute comments and / or in-line whitespace.  Among other things, this means that individual tokens can be split across lines.  Likely the design of this feature was motivated by the prevalence at the time of fixed-width input media such as punched cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* actually a reason why backslash-newlines are processed before comments are removed.  It's the same reason why backslash-newlines are entirely removed, instead of being replaced with (virtual) horizontal whitespace, as comments are. It's a *ridiculous* reason, but it's the official reason. It's so you can mechanically force-fit C code with long lines onto punched cards, by inserting backslash-newline at column 79 no matter what that happens to divide:

```
static int cp_old_stat(struct kstat *stat, struct __old_kernel_stat __user * st\
atbuf)
{
        static int warncount = 5;
        struct __old_kernel_stat tmp;

        if (warncount > 0) {
                warncount--;
                printk(KERN_WARNING "VFS: Warning: %s using old stat() call. Re\
compile your binary.\n",
```

(this is the first chunk of C I found on my hard drive that actually had lines that wouldn't fit on punched cards)

For this to work as intended, backslash-newline has to be able to split a `/*` or a `*/`, like

```
/* this comment just so happens to be exactly 80 characters wide at the close *\
/
```

And you can't have it both ways: if comments were to be removed before processing backslash-newline, then backslash-newline could not affect comment boundaries; conversely, if backslash-newline is to be processed first, then comments can't appear between the backslash and the newline.

(I Am Not Making This Up™: [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n897.pdf) section 5.1.1.2 paragraph 30 reads

> A backslash immediately before a newline has long been used to continue string literals, as well as preprocessing command lines. In the interest of easing machine generation of C, and of transporting code to machines with restrictive physical line lengths, the C89 Committee generalized this mechanism to permit *any* token to be continued by interposing a backslash/newline sequence.

Emphasis in original. Sorry, I don't know of any non-PDF version of this document.)

Comment: Dunno what makes that ridiculous, much less *ridiculous*.  It's not much relevant these days, but it's logical and consistent, enough so that I deduced the fixed-width media connection without looking up the official rationale.

Comment: I should incorporate this information into my answer, but that seems like work. Voted up. Although I agree with John Bollinger, not ridiculous. Computing used to be hard. We had to accept anything we could get.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would bet money that this feature has _never_ been used for its intended purpose, and it makes it substantially harder to implement phases 1-3 + tokenization efficiently.

Comment: I would bet money this feature has been used to put C sources into fixed-length records like those on IBM’s old tape drives (had to specify block sizes, so they were commonly partitioned into some number of records with fixed size), fixed-record-format files on disk, JCL DD statements, “printouts” to punched cards, and so on. Way back when, we did not have those new-fangled new-line characters. What a luxury!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Would you bet money that this was still being done _at the time of the publication of the 1989 C standard_ ?

Comment: I would accept your bet, @zwol, even if you softened that "never" to something a little more forgiving.  I also imagine that such use was rare but not extinct at the time the original standard was being prepared, as fixed-width, record-oriented file formats, including for text / source code, were by no means extinct in the 80's.

Comment: @zwol: I am currently excavating decades of fan-fold printouts from my father’s house (he died last year). He maintained and still developed software for communities working with ancient IBM systems, in emulation and hardware. I am positive fixed-width limitations were still in use and still are—and the only reason my father might not have used this line-splicing for C is he had no interest in new-fangled languages. But I know some of the other people in these communities have been using C.

Comment: @pmg, Eric Postpischil, John Bollinger: Now in the 21th century when designing new tools, should we copy behavior of standard well known tools (such as C prep.)? For ex. line continuation (splicing). While working on one custom prep., initially I've implemented logic, which allows to use comments (or spaces) after backslash character. Then I've looked at the behavior of C prep. and was surprised that in C prep. ``\`` must immediately follow by ``\n``. The core question: should I copy the behavior of C prep. or not? P.S. No punched cards in 21th century.

Comment: @pmor Stack Overflow isn't really geared to help you design something new.

Comment: @pmor If you implement an extension that allows comments after a backslash and still interprets that as a line continuation, then I'd suggest, that you at least allow standard conforming behavior via some commandline option. Although it's unlikely, maybe someone wants a backslash as the last token of a macro expansion. That can be achieved by adding whitespace after the backslash, so it's no longer interpreted as line continuation. Example: https://www.godbolt.org/z/zh4a3q

Answer (score 6):

Lines are spliced together only if a backslash character is the last character on a line. C 2018 5.1.1.2 specifies phases of translating a C program. In phase 2:

> Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines…

If a comment follows a backslash character, the backslash character is not followed by a new-line character, so no splicing is performed. Comments are processed in phase 3:

> The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens7) and sequences of white-space characters (including comments)… Each comment is replaced by one space character…

Regarding the added question:

> What is the motivation / reason / argumentation behind the requirement that (in order to achieve splicing of physical source lines) backslash character (`\`) must immediately follow by a new-line character? What is the obstacle to allow comments (or spaces) after the backslash character (`\`)?

The earliest processing in compiling a C program is the simplest. Early C compilers may have been implemented as layers of simple filters: First local-environment characters or methods of file storage would be translated to a simple stream of characters, then lines would be spliced together (perhaps dealing with a problem of wanting a long source line while having to type your source code on 80-column punched cards), then comments would be removed, and so on.

Splicing together lines marked by a backslash at the end of a line is easy; it only requires looking at two characters. If instead we allow comments to follow the backslash that marks a splice, it becomes complicated:

- A backslash followed by a comment followed by a new-line would be spliced, but a backslash followed by a comment followed by other source code would not. That requires looking possibly many characters ahead and parsing the comment delimiters, possibly for multiple comments.
- One purpose of splicing lines was to allow continuing long strings across multiple lines. (This was before adjacent strings were concatenated in C.) So `"abc\` on one line and `def"` on another would be spliced together, making `"abcdef"`. While we might allow comments after backslashes intended to join lines, we do not want to splice after a line containing `"abc\ /*" /*comment*/`. That means the code doing the splicing has to be context-sensitive; if the backslash appears in a quoted string, it has to treat it differently.

Answer (score 2):

Per [**5.1.1.2 Translation phases** of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) (note the bolded text added)

> **5.1.1.2 Translation phases**
>
> 1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by the following phases.6)
>
> 1 Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation- defined manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations.
>
> 2 **Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice.** A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.
>
> ...

**Only** backslash characters immediately followed by a new-line will cause lines to be spliced.  A comment is not a new-line character.